# MYSQL -- query not listing all records from one of three tables being used

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables.  TBL_C=a list of member's first and last names   TBL_B=a list of group classes offered by each member  TBL_C=a list of membership payments and current membership status.  I need to output the first and last names of members (TBL_A) and all the groups they offer based upon groupTheme selection (TBL_A). In addition to the list, I need to preface the name with a '*' if their status is 'current'(TBL_B).

I have tried the following but it ONLY prints the first record for that particular groupTheme.  If someone taught 2 groups on different days (TBL_A), for instance, I want to see both.

```
 SELECT a.mID, a.ageGroup, a.groupTheme, firstName, lastName, a.dayAvail, a.startTime, a.endTime, b.memberType, MAX( b.paymentDate ) , b.id
    FROM referrals a
    LEFT JOIN members c ON a.mID = c.id
    INNER JOIN membership b ON a.mID = b.memberID
    WHERE a.ageGroup ='preSchool'
    GROUP BY a.mID
    ORDER BY lastName
```

I believe the GROUPBY function is not allowing more than one record thru to the output while IT IS only selecting the latest payment record, thus current status, from TBL_B.

Thank you.

Comment: You are using a pernicious nonstandard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. The presence of this extension makes MySQL return random results. Please consider reading this and redoing your query. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it looks like you're trying to extract a member's most recent payment date using `MAX(b.paymentDate)`. You're quite right that your `GROUP BY` wipes out duplicates.  But your question doesn't explain this particular requirement very clearly, so I am going to guess.

What happens if you use this query instead of the one you gave?

```
    SELECT a.mID, a.ageGroup, a.groupTheme, 
           c.firstName, c.lastName, 
           a.dayAvail, a.startTime, a.endTime
      FROM referrals AS a
 LEFT JOIN members   AS c ON a.mID = c.id
     WHERE a.ageGroup ='preSchool'
  ORDER BY lastName, a.groupTheme
```

Do you get the right number of rows in your result set?  (Obviously you don't get the columns from your `membership` table; we didn't include it in the query).

If so, you're off to a good start. The next step is write a summary query (an aggregate query) against your `membership` table. This query needs to return one row for each member. You haven't told us anything much about that table, so I'm guessing, but here's a possible subquery. I guess you have one row in `membership` for each payment a member has made. So we need to go find the row corresponding to the latest payment.

What we're doing is looking for the highest `id` number in the `membership` table for each member. I am guessing that the `id` column in that table is an AUTO_INCREMENT column, which means that the highest `id` value is the most recent entry. So here's  a query that gets us that little factoid about each member. This little query gives us one row per member.

```
  SELECT MAX(id) AS id, memberID
    FROM membership
   GROUP BY memberId
```

Next, we need to join that query into your overall query to get the most recent information.

That will look like this:

```
    SELECT a.mID, a.ageGroup, a.groupTheme, 
           c.firstName, c.lastName, 
           a.dayAvail, a.startTime, a.endTime
      FROM referrals AS a
 LEFT JOIN members   AS c ON a.mID = c.id
INNER JOIN (    SELECT MAX(id) AS id, 
                       memberID
                  FROM membership
              GROUP BY memberId
            ) AS latestId ON a.mID = latestId.id
     WHERE a.ageGroup ='preSchool'
  ORDER BY lastName, a.groupTheme
```

Do you see the trick here? It's the key to using SQL effectively. We JOINed a subquery as if it was a table. The ability to do that is super important: it's what puts the *Structured* in *Structured Query Language*.

Finally, we need to go get that most-recent row from the membership table and use it in your SELECT clause. That takes yet another JOIN.

```
    SELECT a.mID, a.ageGroup, a.groupTheme, 
           c.firstName, c.lastName, 
           a.dayAvail, a.startTime, a.endTime,
           b.id, b.memberType, b.paymentDate
      FROM referrals AS a
 LEFT JOIN members   AS c ON a.mID = c.id
INNER JOIN (    SELECT MAX(id) AS id,
                       memberID
                  FROM membership
              GROUP BY memberId
            ) AS latestId  ON a.mID = latestId.memberID
INNER JOIN membership AS b ON latestId.id = b.id 
     WHERE a.ageGroup ='preSchool'
  ORDER BY lastName, a.groupTheme
```

Moving the `GROUP BY` to the subquery prevents it from wiping out rows you actually need in your result set.

Be patient with this SQL stuff; it actually does make sense even if it doesn't seem like it.

Comment: You are a genius and a savior!  I knew that an aggregate query was silencing some records and I even thought about a subquery, BUT I didn't have the wherewithal to put it all together and explain it so well as you have done. Your assumptions were spot on! I thank you for your time!  I LOVE STACKOVERFLOW!!